# Sendind an array of custom Objects between activities

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I was following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30688353/how-to-pass-objects-between-activities) answer and trying to adapt it to a List with no success.

The goal is to loop the Activity x amount of times and keep a list that moves a List of a custom Object I have preciously created.

what I am trying to do is:

```
        var MySerializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(partList);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ActComponentForm));
        intent.PutExtra("partList", MySerializedObject);
```

And I try to use the intent doing:

```
List<Components.Component> listParted = new List<Components.Component>();
 try
    {
      var MyJsonString = Intent.GetStringExtra("partList");
      listParted = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Components.Component>>(MyJsonString);

    }
```

With zero sucess as the list doesn't get returned.

Comment: Do you have some error?

Comment: Yes. I get a "System.ArgumentNullException"

Comment: When do you put your extras in first activity I think is not a string extra. Try to use in secent activity not getStringExtra but getExtra or something like this.

Comment: Please check your `MySerializedObject`, make sure it is right. You can also use this `Intent.PutParcelableArrayListExtra()`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putParcelableArrayListExtra(java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList<? extends android.os.Parcelable>) method to pass data. The later is better than the previous in performance.